# Scribd Membership - ebook reader [epubs] DRM Vanishing Text Not able to Copy Paste

Tags: drm

I tried holding ctrlA then holding click up or down the page with also the arrow key as well. It seems to be able to take the pages highlighted but when i am reaching the end of the ebook i press while holding ctrlC to copy then i tried pasting to see if it was good but it just copied the final page i finished. How can i hold all those pages without it vanishing when i let go to copy. They put a protection on it so can someone help with advice? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The text of an epub document is internally stored in XHTML pages, that means you will only be able to copy the active page i.e. the page you are viewing.

If you open the epub document, not with an epub reader, but with an archive program, you can locate the (x)html pages and open them with your browser.

It depends on how the epub document is formatted how much you can copy at a time.